# Facebook Open Graph rate limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app is making exactly 268 calls per user ( not yet live) , but as per new facebook rate limitations its just 200 calls per user. So, caching and making less calls is one option or is there any other? and is that 200 calls per user, is really in implementation now?

Answer (score 0):

Caching and making less calls is the only option. You can test if it´s just a guideline, i assume you can make a bit more too - but in general you should never even remotely hit the limit in a serious App. 200 calls per user per hour is a lot.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting